# Configuration system failed to initialize reading app.config file <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>

Tags: app-config

While reading from my app.config file using vb.net I get a 'Configuration system failed to initialize' error.
The error is occurring with the oracle.manageddataaccess.client
tag.
I am using oracle.manageddataaccess.dll using odp.net to connect to the database.
As we have a number of databases connections I would prefer to keep using the oracle tnsnames.ora file instead of putting in the database alias entry into the app.config file.
If I remove the oracle.manageddataaccess.client tag the vb.net code is reading the app.config without any issue ( I am able to read from ConnectionStrings tag).
The contents of the app.config file is below.
A second issue we have is that when ODP.NET installed when running .Net applications it won't pick up the TNSNAMES.ORA file from the oracle home folder.
It is picking up the TNSNAMES.ORA file from the TNSNAMES.ORA file in the folder
C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2015\network\admin.
If we remove the tnsnames.ora file from this folder the code will not pick up the TNSNAMES.ORA file in the oracle home folder.
Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <settings>
        <setting name="tns_admin" value="E:\oracle11\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin" />
      </settings>
    </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <connectionStrings>
     <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=dbname;User ID=userid;Password=pw;"
             providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```